# Java functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming

In a beginner course about Functional programming in Java, I saw examples such as below:

```
List.of("abc","def").stream().forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));
```

This is the most basic example. In all the other examples, the pattern is almost the same where the stream() function is used. It was mentioned that stream() is to generate a source of objects.

My question is do we need stream ?

Cant it be ? :

```
List.of("abc","def").forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));
```

The other thing I need help to understand is the statement: "In functional programming, functions can be used similar to how data is used."

In the above example, what does that mean?

Does it refer to how the section, `element -> System.out.println(element)` is being used in a way similar to data?

Comment: `List.of("abc","def").forEach(System.out::println);` would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is do we need stream ?

Not for this example. `forEach` is a unique snowflake; it's the only one that is on list directly, most other stream things (`map`, `filter`, `max`, that sort of thing) is only on stream.

More generally, `forEach` should never be used. It's strictly inferior to a normal for loop. It isn't transparent in 3 ways:

- It is not control flow transparent (you cannot break/continue a loop defined outside a lambda from inside it; you also cannot return the method that contains the lambda from inside one).
- It is not checked exception transparent (you cannot `throw` checked exceptions inside a lambda even if the context around the lambda catches them).
- It is not mutable local variable transparent: You cannot read or write to any local variable defined outside the lambda, unless that variable is (effectively) `final`.

These are significant downsides. There are situations where all 3 are irrelevant, but there isn't an upside to lambdas either, hence, don't use `list.forEach` with a lambda.

`forEach` on list itself is *only* to be used when you have a `Consumer<T>` already from elsewhere, say, in a field perhaps.

The `forEach` method on streams can be used, but it doesn't make any sense unless you have applied a series of stream operations. For example, this:

```
list.stream()
  .filter(x -> x.length() > 6)
  .map(String::toLowerCase()
  .forEach(System.out::println)
  ;
```

Is probably still not a good idea (just use a for loop) but it's less egregiously "Must... use... shiny... new... hammer!" as `list.forEach(x ->...)`.

> In functional programming, functions can be used similar to how data is used.

Bit of a nebulous statement. It's generally referring to the notion that functions can be passed around like variables. You can write a function that logs how many elements are removed from a string, for example, and you want the caller to pass to this function "how can I tell if an element should be removed?". Which you can do:

```
public static <T> int removeIfCount(List<T> elems, Predicate<T> filter) {
  int a = elems.size();
  elems.removeIf(filter);
  int b = elems.size();
  return b - a;
}
```

Here calling code could e.g. call:

```java
List<String> names = ...;
int count = removeIfCount(names, x -> x.length() > 6);
```

Which removes all names longer than 6 characters long and gives you a count of how many were removed. Here we pass the function around like data - our `removeIfCount` code just accepts the function as a `Predicate<T>` variable and passes it along. Exactly like how one might pass data around.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just try to explain difference between `Collections` and `Streams`, which explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

> Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities, have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast, streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their elements, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing their source and the computational operations which will be performed in aggregate on that source.

Also if we check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams#referencing), it can be help to understand what is `Stream`, and why it said

> It was mentioned that stream() is to generate a source of objects.